# How to swap signal without iterrows or itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm struglling with `pandas`, I'm trying to define the B col as true after A col return 1, then return false when A col return 1 again.

Any ideas how to make this happen without iterrows or itertuples?

```
  A B 
0 0 false
1 0 false
2 1 true
3 0 true
4 0 true
5 1 true
6 0 false
7 0 false
```

Comment: `df['B'] = np.logical_xor.accumulate(df.A) | df.A`, if 'true' and 'false' should be `True` and `False`

Comment: In other words, the first row appearing with the value 1 in A col will return True and the following data will need to return false if A col returns 1 again?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew will be True when 1 apper on A, and keep true until 1 appear again and back to fasle.